# How to skip php 8 libs installation during installation of phpmyadmin

Tags: server, php, phpmyadmin

**My server environment is as follows :**

Ubuntu 18.04 
Mysql : 5.6 Installed
Php : 5.6 Installed

Im trying to install phpmyadmin by executing sudo apt install phpmyadmin  which give me following prompt

**The following additional packages will be installed:**

`dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc libzip4 php-mysql php-pear php-php-gettext php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php-zip php8.0-common php8.0-mysql php8.0-zip`

although I have all the libs installed for php 5.6 it gives me above prompt. My application supports php 5.6 only so how can I skip php 8 installation at this stage ?

Answer (score 0):

To use `PHP 5.6` you have to download `phpmyadim 4.9.7`. You can download it with `wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.7/phpMyAdmin-4.9.7-all-languages.tar.gz`.

Comment: Im looking for automated process